# How to test if a function is called on window.onerror

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How do I test if a function is called during the onerror event of the window object using Jasime.

I have a module which exposes a couple of functions

```
//errortracking.ts

export function reportError(
  msg,
  url,
  lineNo,
  columnNo,
  err,
  service,
  errorServer
) {
  const string = msg.toLowerCase();
  const substring = "script error";
  let error = new Error(`Unknown error`);

  if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
    error = new Error(msg);
  } else if (err) {
    error = err;
  }
  const errorReport: { error: Error; params: { service: string } } = {
    params: { service },
    error
  };

  errorServer.notify(errorReport);
  return false;
}
```

And in a separate module I set this function to window.onerror

```
const { onerror } = window;
  window.onerror = function catchAll(...args) {
    onerror.apply(this, args);
    return reportError.apply(this, [...args, serviceLabel, errorServer]);
  };
```

How can I write my test in Jasmine such that I know reportError is always called window.onerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a spy for the `reportError` function, then depending on what happens inside the function, either `callThrough` so the actual function is called, write a dummy function that doesn't accidentally write to the database, or just leave it as is.

In any case, a spy object can be used to assert that a function has been called:

```
// Import the entire module so we can use `jasmine.spyOn`, which requires
// an object and a key inside that object, but cannot handle a function object

import * as Errors from 'errortracking.ts';
jasmine.spyOn(Errors, 'reportError');

// You can check whether the function was called at al
it("calls reportError when something fails", function() {
  const fail = 1 / 0;
  expect(Errors.reportError).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

// Or check whether the arguments are also correct
it("calls reportError with the correct arguments", function() {
  const fail = 1 / 0;
  expect(Errors.reportError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* specific arguments */);
});
```